# Как сделать вывод для каждой страницы на WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть несколько страниц на Wordpress.
Для каждой странице нужно вывести несколько полей.

Есть выбор города (страницы) в каждом городе (странице) есть офисы адреса которых нужно вывести. Как это реализовать ? ACF не помогло так-как офисов может быть несколько.

Comment: Чего это ACF не помогло. В ACF pro есть repeater. А можно и на странице задать метаполя в любом количестве и их считывать.

Comment: Поставил другой плагин в котором   repeater бесплатный. Все получилось. Спасибо !